# Just me or is tag highlighting not functioning?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stackexchange

Traditionally, a question containing one of a user's designated "favorite" tags would highlight with that mustard-yellow background.

I'm not seeing any highlighting the past few days? Is this a known issue or is it merely my browser?

Looking at various stacks.. it's the same on all of them.. must be stack wide then??

Comment: Relevant? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366321/ignored-and-watched-tags-seem-broken

Comment: Thanks @curious seems to be a stack issue. (I DID search meta on this.. but yesterday.. not today `:)` )

Comment: Soon we'll hear that it's a paid feature for the low price of $1.99/month "Tag Watching"...

Comment: But it's only $19.99 if paid annually! That's a savings of **nearly FIVE DOLLARS!** `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a current issue across the entire Stack Exchange network.

[Ignored and watched tags seem broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366321/ignored-and-watched-tags-seem-broken)

Based upon comments on Meta.. the powers that be are working on fixing the issue.